# iterating backward in a row within a 2d array

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array

I hope someone can help me with this. My problem is that I have a 2D int array in Java. It looks like this:

[image]

I need to find the index of the last `2` in row `0`. I already tried to iterate backward with an inverse for each loop, but that just mirrored the whole array. What I need is just the index number. In this case it should be row `0` col `3`.

I also tried to do it in a while loop, but it also doesn't print the right value and I don't know why. It only prints 2.

```
int x = ans.length;
int y = ans[0].length;
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);
while(y - 1>= 0 ) {
    System.out.println("In");
    y--;
    if(ans[0][y] != 0) {
        x = ans[0][y];
        System.out.println(x);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to iterate backward or inverse:

```
public class StackOveFlow {

   
    static int[][] matrix = {
            {2,2,0,2,0,0},
            {0,2,2,2,2,2},
            {2,2,2,2,2,0},
            {0,2,2,0,0,0},
            {2,2,2,0,1,1}
        };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int rowToSearch = 0;
        int integerToFind = 2;
        int lastOccurance = findLastOccurrance(rowToSearch,integerToFind);
        if(lastOccurance>-1)
            System.out.println("Found last " + integerToFind + " in row " + rowToSearch + " at column = " + lastOccurance);
        else
            System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
       
       
    }
    public static int findLastOccurrance(int row, int intToFind)
    {
        int index = -1;
        for(int column = 0; column < 6;column++)
            if(matrix[row][column]==intToFind)
                index = column;
        
        return index;
    }
}
```

Iterating reverse will be useful if you have large array.. Backward iteration can done with minute changes for loop.